# Correct RESTful call for this resource

Tags: rest, restful-url

I'm currently designing a RESTful interface to an existing infrastructure and I'm struggling with one particular aspect.

We have a collection of users which can be accessed at `/users`
And elements of that collection can be accessed at `/users/1` etc

However each user has a list of friends which needs to be able to accessed as well. Would `users/1/friends` be the restful call to make here? It doesn't qualify to be a collection of it's own since it's relates to only one user.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as RESTful design is concerned, the URI can be whatever you want.  However, to ensure your interface can be accessed in a RESTfully you do need to do something like this:

```
<user>
    <name>Bob Smith</name>
    <link rel="friends" href="/peeps/1/amigos" />
</user>
```

By adding the extra layer of indirection, your client can discover the link for the list of friends and it no longer matters to the client what that URI is.  You can change it whenever you like.

URIs are an implementation detail of the server and clients should never couple on them.  The only coupling should be on rels and media types.

Comment: I'd disagree that URIs are only an implementation detail since they are actually identifying your resources. A good RESTful design should take this into account in order to improve meaning and semantics.

Comment: @PartlyCloudy A client that infers semantics from a URI is violating REST principles.  URIs should be completely opaque to the client.  You should be able to run an obfuscator on URIs just like you can on procedure names and the client should still work.  That doesn't mean it is not valuable to the developer to be able to read the URI.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say `/user/{id}/friends` is an appropriate identifier. Of course you can also use `/users/{id}/friends`, but I personally prefer to differentiate between item resources and collection resources.

Answer (score 1):

I dont see see anything wrong with your solution. Perfectly good selection as a URI for what it represents.